# How to loop faster through Dataset while using AES 256 algorithm c#.net?

Tags: c#

In C# in am looping through 50k records. while looping i am calling AES 256 algorithm to Encrypt/Decrypt Number filed, after encrypting i am assigning the Encrypt/Decrypt text to same field. so for 50k records it is taking approximately 40 min. which is a constraint for performance. Here is my code

```
public string Encrypt(string plainText)
{
    try
    {
        _saltSize = 32;
        encrypt_key = "200911381f7899d2482ab61fe8d15684469b17fc690";

        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(plainText))
        {
            throw new ArgumentNullException("plainText");
        }

        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(encrypt_key))
        {
            throw new ArgumentNullException("Password_To_Encrypt_key");
        }


        var keyDerivationFunction = new Rfc2898DeriveBytes(encrypt_key, _saltSize);

        byte[] saltBytes = keyDerivationFunction.Salt;
        byte[] keyBytes = keyDerivationFunction.GetBytes(32);
        byte[] ivBytes = keyDerivationFunction.GetBytes(16);

        using (var aesManaged = new AesManaged())
        {
            aesManaged.KeySize = 256;

            using (var encryptor = aesManaged.CreateEncryptor(keyBytes, ivBytes))
            {
                MemoryStream memoryStream = null;
                CryptoStream cryptoStream = null;

                return WriteMemoryStream(plainText, ref saltBytes, encryptor, ref memoryStream, ref cryptoStream);
            }
        }
    }
    catch (Exception)
    {

        throw;
    }
}
```

Comment: Well have you worked out what the bottleneck is? If it's the encryption, have you considered doing this in parallel?

Comment: Can you show us the code? Can you show us which line is slowest? Without additional information your question is unanswerable. Its like me saying "my commute to work is too long and I drive a car on the way", and asking, "how can I make it faster ?" Without knowing more about my journey its not possible to know if my problem is traffic, my cars speed, my route, the distance from the car park to my office or whatever else.

Comment: Yup, show us the code, encryption itself shouldn't deteriorate a loop's performance.

Comment: @kenlacoste: It can. If used improperly.

Comment: `CTRL-C CTRL-V` your source code it takes 40msec

Comment: @SaniHuttunen Well, true especially if you're pertaining to a very heavy encryption options as parameters. However I've never been "INTO" that so basic encryption should suffice as for me as NOT that deteriorating. ;)

Comment: @0x90: For a single encyption yes: Try 1000 calls to `EncryptRfc`.  Or even 50 000 as the OP is trying.

Comment: @sani  Posting source code in the question is a must. I don't really get your point. How the code length is depended on wether it is 1k or 50k entries?

Comment: @0x90: I misunderstood your comment. I thought it was referring to MY code and that the execution time of my code was 40ms. :)

Comment: @abhayk: The problem is probably that you call `Encrypt` 50 000 times. You need to refactor your code so that the call to Encrypt doesn't contain the `Rfc2898DeriveBytes` when you loop over the DataSet.

Comment: @SaniHuttunen: you are Correct! I am calling that code 50k times.... is it fine if i call Rfc2898DeriveBytes only once and process all the 50k records?

Comment: @abhayk: Yes. Modify your code according to the instructions in my post.

Comment: @SaniHuttunen: you are my saviour.. thank you very much.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

My guess is that you do something similar to this:

```
public static byte[] EncryptRfc(byte[] plainText, string password, byte[] salt)
{
  var keyGen = new Rfc2898DeriveBytes(password, salt);
  var key = keyGen.GetBytes(32);
  var iv = keyGen.GetBytes(16);

  var cipher = new RijndaelManaged { Key = key, IV = iv };

  byte[] cipherText;
  using (var encryptor = cipher.CreateEncryptor()) {
    using (var ms = new MemoryStream()) {
      using (var cs = new CryptoStream(ms, encryptor, CryptoStreamMode.Write)) {
        cs.Write(plainText, 0, plainText.Length);
        cs.FlushFinalBlock();
        cipherText = ms.ToArray();
      }
    }
  }
  return cipherText;
}
```

The problem here is the initialization of `Rfc2898DeriveBytes` and subsequent calls to `GetBytes` which takes a considerable amount of time when generating the first key. (See [this blog post](https://jmpstart.wordpress.com/2009/09/29/proper-use-of-rfc2898derivebytes/) for more information.)

What you should do is lift out `Rfc2898DeriveBytes` from the method:

```
public static byte[] EncryptRfc(string plaintext, byte[] key, byte[] iv)
{
  var cipher = new RijndaelManaged { Key = key, IV = iv };

  ...

  return cipherText;
}
```

And then call the encryption function with the `Key` and `IV`

```
...
var keyGen = new Rfc2898DeriveBytes(password, salt);
var key = keyGen.GetBytes(32);
...
foreach (var line in AllDataToEncryptCollectionOfStrings)
{
  ...
  var iv = keyGen.GetBytes(16);
  var encryptedData = EncryptRfc(plainText, key, iv);
  ...
}
```

This will reduce the execution time to about 1/4 of the original time. If you need it to run even faster then use the same Key and IV for all encryptions:

```
...
var keyGen = new Rfc2898DeriveBytes(password, salt);
var key = keyGen.GetBytes(32);
var iv = keyGen.GetBytes(16);
...
foreach (var line in AllDataToEncryptCollectionOfStrings)
{
  ...
  var encryptedData = EncryptRfc(plainText, key, iv);
  ...
}
```

The last piece of code will run in a fraction of the time (50 000 calls to EncryptRfc takes, on my computer, about 300ms).

Mind though that the level of security decreases when using the same IV for multiple encryptions.

But all this is just guesswork since you haven't provided any code from your attempts.

Comment: this might be a good answer, I can't tell what the question is.

Comment: @Jodrell: Yes indeed. As stated this is pure guesswork but from the timings stated in the OP this might be a plausable scenario if you see the findings in the linked blog post.

Comment: @SaniHuttunen: does it going to make any difference if i lift out  
var key = new Rfc2898DeriveBytes(passwordBytes, saltBytes, 1000);

Comment: @abhayk: Since you still haven't posted you code I cannot answer that.

Comment: @SaniHuttunen: i am using the exact code what you have posted and the same algorithm. if you want code still i can post it after some time.. now some other guy is using that machine... so i can not login :( ... i have copied the code from [link](www.codeproject.com/Articles/769741/Csharp-AES-bits-Encryption-Library-with-Salt)

Comment: @abhayk: Read my post again and adjust your code accordingly.

Comment: @SaniHuttunen: i have posted my code in question please check.

Comment: @abhayk: The link you posted has exactly the same design flaw my post illustrates. I've seen this many times before and it's a common mistake to make.

Comment: It appears the salt is being reused.  This renders the salt pointless and increases the chance of the encryption being hacked.